# Can not create a folder 'res/transition' after updating SDK to Kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-animation, android-resources, transition, android-4.4-kitkat

I have updated my **Android SDK to Kitkat 4.4.2,** and trying to explore '**android.transition**'. As per mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html) , TransitionManagers can be declared in XML resource files inside the res/transition directory. But when i created the directory under **res/transition**, Eclipse shows error as shown in this figure.

[image]

What can be the possible solution to this??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try refreshing? I'm using Kitkat as well (I started out with Kitkat though, didn't update) and I was able to add the directory without any errors.

Comment: Ok.. but I restarted the Eclipse but couldn't solve the issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your SDK build tool to latest one using SDK Manager.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.let me try it.